# Gulp: how to copy contents of a directory recursively, without the matched parent?

Tags: gulp

I'd like to copy the contents of a directory recursively, but without the parent directory (foo in my example).

```
gulp.task('copy', ['clean:tmp'], function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/foo/**/*'], {base:"src"})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/.tmp/'));
});
```

This produces the following hieararchy:

```
src/.tmp/foo/{contents}
```

But I would like to have it without the `foo` folder:

```
src/.tmp/{contents}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ base: 'src/foo' }`

Should solve your problem. You have to define the base explicitly.